# How to show multiple google native ad in flutter

Tags: flutter, admob, google-mobile-ads

I am trying to call an **ad** dynamically in a `listview` but throws this error :

```
If you placed this AdWidget in a list, make sure you create a new instance in the builder function with a unique ad object.
Make sure you are not using the same ad object in more than one AdWidget.
```

Here is the code

Import package `google_mobile_ads`

```
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
```

Then instantiated the package

```
NativeAd _nativeAd;

final Completer<NativeAd> nativeAdCompleter = Completer<NativeAd>();
```

I function to load the Ads

```
loadAd(){
    _nativeAd = NativeAd(
      adUnitId: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1044960115",
      request: AdRequest(),
      factoryId: 'adFactoryExample',
      listener: AdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
          print('$NativeAd loaded.');
          nativeAdCompleter.complete(ad as NativeAd);
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError error) {
          ad.dispose();
          print('$NativeAd failedToLoad: $error');
          nativeAdCompleter.completeError(null);
        },
        onAdOpened: (Ad ad) => print('$NativeAd onAdOpened.'),
        onAdClosed: (Ad ad) => print('$NativeAd onAdClosed.'),
        onApplicationExit: (Ad ad) => print('$NativeAd onApplicationExit.'),
      ),
    );
    Future<void>.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () => _nativeAd?.load());
  }
```

Then to show the add I did this in a switch case statement

```
case 'ad':
                                  loadAd();

                                  return FutureBuilder<NativeAd>(
                                    future: nativeAdCompleter.future,
                                    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<NativeAd> snapshot) {
                                      Widget child;

                                      switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                                        case ConnectionState.none:
                                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                                        case ConnectionState.active:
                                          child = Container();
                                          break;
                                        case ConnectionState.done:
                                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                            child = AdWidget(ad: _nativeAd);
                                          } else {
                                            child = Text('Error loading $NativeAd');
                                          }
                                      }

                                      return Scaffold(
                                        body: Container(
                                          width: double.infinity,
                                          height: double.infinity,
                                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 100, left: 5, right: 5, bottom: 70),
                                          child: Center(child: child),
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    },
                                  );
                                  break;
```

This integration throws the above exception while showing ads from the second ad

Comment: not an error its the answer..

Answer (score 2):

To show multiple google *native* ads in flutter *ListView* you need to focus on the below 3 steps.

I assume you already follow the process to show Native Ads in a flutter.
[Create Native ads](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/admob-inline-ads-in-flutter#7)

Step 1: Create a different **Future** function as below in a separate dart file.

```
static Future<Widget> getNativeAdTest({
    required BuildContext context,
  }) async {
    bool isAdLoaded = false;
    NativeAd _listAd = NativeAd(
      adUnitId: AdHelper.nativeAdUnitId,
      factoryId: "listTile",
      request: const AdRequest(),
      listener: NativeAdListener(onAdLoaded: (ad) {
        isAdLoaded = true;
        if (kDebugMode) {
          // print("ad load");
        }
      }, onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, error) {
        // _listAd.dispose();
        if (kDebugMode) {
          print("faild to load add ${error.message}");
        }
      }),
    );
    await _listAd.load();
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4));
    return AdWidget(
      ad: _listAd,
      key: Key(_listAd.hashCode.toString()),
    );
  }
```

Step 2: Use **ListView.separated()** **itemBuilder** will show list content and **separatorBuilder** will show Ads.(you can skip if you want to use as any child)

Step 3: Use **FutureBuilder()** in the child widget as below to get data after ad load.

```
return FutureBuilder(
      future: AdHelper.getNativeAdTest(context: context),
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          AdWidget ad = snapshot.data as AdWidget;
          print("snap: $snapshot");
          return Container(
            height: 90,
            child: ad,
          );
        } else {
          return Container(
              alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              child: const CircularProgressIndicator(
                value: 0.8,
              ));
        }
      });
```

Comment: thnk uh soo much man im trying from 2 days and finally it works dont have option to mar it tick .TANKS

Answer (score 1):

I'm really not sure how you have implemented the widget since you only show the part of you class but I believe it should work if you made the isolated widget for Native ad and place initialisation of `NativeAd` in `initState` like this.

Then you can use `NativeAdWidget` in your list view.

```dart
class NativeAdWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => NativeAdState();
}

class NativeAdState extends State<NativeAdWidget> {
  NativeAd _nativeAd;
  final Completer<NativeAd> nativeAdCompleter = Completer<NativeAd>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _nativeAd = NativeAd(
      adUnitId: Platform.isAndroid ? getIt<Vars>().androidNativeId : getIt<Vars>().iosNativeId,
      request: const AdRequest(nonPersonalizedAds: true),
      customOptions: <String, Object>{},
      factoryId: getIt<Vars>().admobFactoryId,
      listener: AdListener(
        onAdLoaded: (Ad ad) {
          nativeAdCompleter.complete(ad as NativeAd);
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (Ad ad, LoadAdError err) {
          unawaited(HandleError.logError(err.message));
          ad.dispose();
          nativeAdCompleter.completeError(null);
        },
        onAdOpened: (Ad ad) => print('$ad onAdOpened.'),
        onAdClosed: (Ad ad) => print('$ad onAdClosed.'),
        onApplicationExit: (Ad ad) => print('$ad onApplicationExit.'),
      ),
    );

    _nativeAd?.load();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _nativeAd?.dispose();
    _nativeAd = null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<NativeAd>(
      future: nativeAdCompleter.future,
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<NativeAd> snapshot) {
        Widget child;

        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
          case ConnectionState.active:
            child = Container();
            break;
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              child = AdWidget(ad: _nativeAd);
            } else {
              child = Text('Error loading ad');
            }
        }

        return Container(
          height: 330,
          child: child,
          color: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```